# How do I monitor clicks on ads from my site?

Tags: web-services, web, ads

I would like to put some ads on my site.
All I have is jpegs of the ads. I would like to know when a user clicked my ads, and which.

I figure I put a heading for the links address:

```
http://cocacola.com
  |
   --> http://someadservice.com?goto=http://cocacola.com&senderID=1234
```

Does that makes sense?

What services are there (preferably free) that I can use for that and how do they work?

Comment: You can redirect the user to a php script that can update the counter in the database ....and then redirect him to the addvertisement..

Comment: You can do that using PHP , AJAX or any otheer web scripting language you are comfortable with.

Answer (score 1):

To reliably count a click, you would send the user to your own server and then redirect him to the final ad destination.
The you can count all the requests on your server.

All advertising platforms offer a similar kind of tracking, since they usually charge by click (called CPC).